# Stored Procedure inserted values can't access by other mysql user

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, permissions

I create a stored procedure in below code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`john`@`%` PROCEDURE `new_type`(IN typ_id int(11), `typ_name` varchar(100))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_type (`typ_id`,`typ_name`,`usr_id`) VALUES (typ_id,usr_typ_name,usr_id)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY  UPDATE  `typ_name` = VALUES(typ_name),
  `usr_id` = VALUES(usr_id);
END
```

The insert and update working good. The issue on selection, I have two user account in MYSQL. The procedure created by john and he have only access rights of this database only. Another user name called 'Admin' and he have all access rights to all database. The result of select query is various. see the example.

For result of Admin

> 1 'Admin', '4'
>
> 2 'Manger', '5'
>
> 3 'Secretary', '6'

For result of John

> 1 'Admin', '4'
>
> 2 'Manger', '5'
>
> 3 'Secretary', '6'
>
> 4 'User', '7'
>
> 5 'Assist Mager', '8'

Why the admin user didn't get the **'User' , 'Assist Mager'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give full access to admin user then you need to give `grant all privileges` to it.

SQL GRANT is a command used to provide access or privileges on the database objects to the users.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```